# What are the best practicies for update list?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Entity contains list of tags. Client receives the updated list of tag ids. Some tags need remove from list, and some add to list. I decide this problem for the following way:

There are two classes

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

And Update method

```
public void UpdateEntityTags(int entityId, int[] tags)
{
    var entity = _context.Entities.Find(entityId);

    var sourceTags = entity.Tags.Select(x => x.TagId);

    var removeList = sourceTags.Except(tags);
    var tagsForRemove = entity.Tags.Where(x => removeList.Contains(x.TagId));
    entity.Tags.RemoveRange(tagsForRemove);

    var addList = tags.Except(sourceTags);
    var tagsForAdd = _context.Tags.Where(x => removeList.Contains(x.TagId));
    entity.Tags.AddRange(tagsForAdd);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is that good way, or is there better?

Comment: It looks fine for me :)

Comment: Tags need to be removed/added based on what criteria? How are people supposed to tell you if this is a good solution without knowing the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

As I also mentioned in a comment, you need to explain the requirements so people can tell you whether there's a better way of doing what you need to do, however, even without knowing the requirements, I can tell you there's something wrong with your logic.

You are first removing all the tags that are not in the `tags` array from `entity.Tags`, and then you are adding all the tags from the `tags` array that where not in the `entity.Tags` before the tags where removed. Instead of that you can just remove all the tags, and add everything in the `tags` array. So, your method can be simplified to this:

```
public void UpdateEntityTags(int entityId, int[] tags)
{
    var entity = _context.Entities.Find(entityId);

    entity.Tags.RemoveAll();
    entity.Tags.AddRange(tags);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```